# How does Maven handle dependencies between modules?

Tags: maven, dependencies

According to the [Maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html),  `mvn install` will "install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally". The local repository then stores all the jars that I downloaded remotely.

My modules have dependencies with other modules. When I run `mvn package`, nothing is stored in my local repository, but the dependencies appear to be fulfilled. So how does Maven handle the inter-module dependencies? Does Maven refer to the jars of each module from the built target directories or does it fetch them from another location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corey,

You are correct, going strictly by Maven docs implies `mvn compile` on:

```
parent_pom/
  subA/
    pom.xml
  subB/
    pom.xml    # depends on subA
```

should fail since subA hasn't been pushed out to the local repo.

What's happening under the hood is that Maven uses the `reactor` to trick the build into looking into `target` dir of earlier submodules on the same build.

Beyond the scope of this particular question, the [maven-reactor-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-reactor-plugin/) is one of the most opaque parts of Maven, but also one of the most powerful if you master it.  You would do well to read up on it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the phase you're executing. Before `compile`, Maven will fail, since there are no classes compiled. Between `compile` and `package`, the `target/classes` is used. For `package` and later, the `target/artifactId-version.jar` is used.